# How want to add pagination for the json data which i am fetching from the AWS S3 bucket in laravel?

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, bucket

```php
$adnoc = Storage::disk('s3')->get('adnoc.json');

$adnocArr = json_decode($adnoc, true);
```

This is how I am fetching the data, but all data is fetched. But I am trying to use limit(10) which is not working in laravel.

I want to get fist 10 data, than the next 10, and next 10 like that, so that i can make a pagination for it, else all data is fetched and which takes lot of time to load the page.

Comment: `Storage::get()` is always going to pull down the full JSON file, even if you paginate what you send to the user in the browser. You should consider a database for the data if you intend to use it this way. If you want to use `limit()` on a JSON array, you'll probably want to first turn it into a Laravel Collection via `collect($adnocArr)`.